# Spring boot + kotlin runApplication<MyApplication>(*args) can not start

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

```
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

@SpringBootApplication
open  class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```

> Error: unable to find or unable to load the main class

Why can't that run, but this can?

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

@SpringBootApplication
open class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing following import in your Kotlin code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
```

Adding it should fix the problem.

On the other hand, this import is **not** necessary:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
```